# Display the textbox and list next each other using css/html

Tags: html, css

Hi Im trying to get the layout like in the image but Im not able to get the expected layout.Right now its like, If I get two boxes correct, another one goes wrong or get misplaced over another `<div>`,so how do it get it correct. I know it easy but not able to get the css correctly.

[image]

```css
  #first {
      border: 1px solid black;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 300px; 
      float:left;
      height:300px; 
      margin:20px
  }


  #second {
      width: 100px; 
      float:left; 
      height:100px;
      margin:20px
  }

  #third {
      width: 600px;
      float: left;
      height: 100px;
      border: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
        <div>
          <div id="first">
                <ul>
                  <li>Apple</li>
                  <li>Orange</li>
                  <li>Lime</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <label> DESCRIPTION</label>
            <div id="second">
                <br />
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> Description</textarea>
                <br />
                <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)} > submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
         <ul>
           <li>Daisy</li>
           <li>Jasmine</li>
           <li>Rose</li>
         </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started using flex boxes.

I will leave padding and margins for you figure out.
Check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp to learn how to use flex boxes.

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1 0;
}

button {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
}

.outer {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="div1 border"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div2 border"></div>
    <div>
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="div2 border"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="div1">

    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <button>
      hello
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right{
   width: 60%;
   margin: 15px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: lightgray;
   float:left;
}
.left{
   width: 30%;
   margin: 15px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: lightyellow;
   float:left;
}

.div1{
  height: 40%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.div2{
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}
.div3{
    height: 40%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You dont have #third div id.
Second you could put all the divs into a Main div and work from there.

```css
  #Main{..}


  #first {
      border: 1px solid black;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 300px; 
      float:left;
      height:300px; 
      margin:20px
  }


  #second {
      width: 100px; 
      float:left; 
      height:100px;
      margin:20px
  }

  #third {
      width: 600px;
      float: left;
      height: 100px;
      border: 10px;
  }
```

```html
        <div id="Main">
          <div id="first">
                <ul>
                  <li>Apple</li>
                  <li>Orange</li>
                  <li>Lime</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <label> DESCRIPTION</label>
            <div id="second">
                <br />
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> Description</textarea>
                <br />
                <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)} > submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Third">
         <ul>
           <li>Daisy</li>
           <li>Jasmine</li>
           <li>Rose</li>
         </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look: 
https://jsfiddle.net/r8r5Ldq3/

```
<div>
  <div id="first">
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
      <li>Lime</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <label> DESCRIPTION</label>
    <div id="second">
      <br />
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> Description</textarea>
      <br />
      <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}> submit</button>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      <ul>
        <li>Daisy</li>
        <li>Jasmine</li>
        <li>Rose</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
 #first {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 300px;
   float: left;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 20px
 }

 #second {
   width: 100px;
 }

 #third {
   border: 10px;
 }

 #test {
   float: left;
 }
```